# Odoo V8 Got error unhashable type : 'list'

Tags: python, odoo-8

ive got error like this :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 544, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 581, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 317, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 314, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 810, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 410, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5989, in onchange
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5887, in _onchange_eval
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5395, in _convert_to_cache
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5396, in <dictcomp>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 1661, in convert_to_cache
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\tools\misc.py", line 1288, in add
  File "collections.pyc", line 63, in __setitem__
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

ive checked it using pdb, but i got no error in my code, but got in this part :

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5887, in _onchange_eval

    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

and here is my code, my goal is to override onchange_employee_id function from hr.payslip model, and want to update the one2many field lines values by using (1,ID, {values}) :

```
import openerp
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import api, fields, models, _, SUPERUSER_ID
from datetime import datetime
import time

class hr_payslip(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

    #@api.model
    #@api.multi
    def onchange_employee_id(self, cr, uid, ids, date_from, date_to, employee_id=False, contract_id=False, context=None):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        res = super(hr_payslip, self).onchange_employee_id(cr, uid, ids, date_from, date_to, employee_id=employee_id, contract_id=contract_id, context=context)
        #res = super(hr_payslip, self).onchange_employee_id(cr, uid, ids, date_from, date_to, employee_id, contract_id, context)
        for pay in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
            empy = self.pool.get('overtime_details').search(cr, uid, [
                                ('start_date','>=',datetime.strptime(pay.date_from, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 
                                ('end_date','<=',datetime.strptime(pay.date_to, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 
                                ('employee_id.name','=',pay.employee_id.name), 
                                ('overtime_id.state', '=', 'done')], context=context)
            if pay.id:
                #chk_struct = self.pool.get('hr.payroll.structure').search(cr, uid, [('name', '=', pay.struct_id.name)], context=context)
                #chk_contract = self.pool.get('hr.contract').search(cr, uid, [('name', '=', pay.contract_id.name)], context=context)
                if empy:
                    #if chk_struct:
                        #if chk_contract:
                    chk_ovt = self.pool.get('overtime_details').browse(cr, uid, empy, context=context)
                    if chk_ovt:
                        counter = 0
                        hrs = 0
                        vals = []
                        for ovt in chk_ovt:
                            if ovt.id:
                                counter = counter + 1
                                hrs = hrs + ovt.ttalmtp
                    vals.append([1,[pay.worked_days_line_ids],{'number_of_days':counter, 
                    'number_of_hours':hrs, 'contract_id':pay.contract_id}])
                    return {'value' : {'worked_days_line_ids' : vals }}
                                #self.create(cr, uid, val2)
                else :
                    val = 0

            return res
```

what should i do to fix the error

thanks before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ive got the solution so instead using (1,ID,{values}) iam using (0,0,{values})
and update it later, here is my code solution :

```
vals.append([0,0,{'number_of_days':counter, 
                'number_of_hours':hrs, 'contract_id':pay.contract_id}])
                ovrtm = {'worked_days_line_ids' : vals }
                res['value'].update(ovrtm)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
return {'value' : {'worked_days_line_ids' : vals }}
```

You try to insert a `list` into a dictionary, however, this is impossible as `list`s are *unhashable*. You can solve it by converting the list to a `tuple`:

```
return {'value' : {'worked_days_line_ids' : tuple(vals)}}
```

Comment: still got error at the same line but with different warning like this : `ValueError: Wrong value for hr.payslip.worked_days_line_ids: ([1, [hr.payslip.worked_days(6, 7, 8)], {'number_of_days': 2, 'contract_id': hr.contract(1,), 'number_of_hours': 21.5}],)`

Comment: ive got the solution, thanks for ur answer that enlightment me :)